# Date frequency detection, but one that occurs most often

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am looking for a way to check the frequency of dates in a column. I have a date with a frequency of every week, but sometimes there is a hurdle of 2 or 3 weeks, and the `pd.infer_freq` method returns NaN.

My data:

```
2022-01-01
2022-01-08
2022-01-23
2022-01-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is too small for `pd.infer_freq` to be able to infer the frequencies. You could find the most common time difference between consecutive days and use that to infer the frequency -

```py
s = pd.Series(dates)
print((s - s.shift(1)).mode())
```

**Output**

```
0   7 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```